# Use selected item from DropDownList to query another table and fill textboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, razor

I want to get the description and price of the selected artikel, but i want to be able to edit it afterwards so for example you have a standard price which can be adjusted.

Here is what my database looks like.[image: DataModel]

Here is my view code. (I left out some input fields)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ArtikelID, "ArtikelID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("ArtikelID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ArtikelID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ArtikelBeschrijving, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ArtikelBeschrijving, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ArtikelBeschrijving, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ArtikelPrijs, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ArtikelPrijs, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ArtikelPrijs, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and the controller for the view.

```
        // GET: Orders/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.ArtikelID = new SelectList(db.Artikels, "ArtikelID", "ArtikelNummer");
            ViewBag.PaardID = new SelectList(db.Paarden, "PaardID", "Naam");
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Orders/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "OrderID,Ordernummer,PaardID,KlantNaam,PaardNaam,ChipNummer,Levensnummer,ArtikelID,ArtikelBeschrijving,ArtikelPrijs,Datum")] Orders orders)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Orders.Add(orders);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            ViewBag.ArtikelID = new SelectList(db.Artikels, "ArtikelID", "ArtikelNummer", orders.ArtikelID);
            ViewBag.PaardID = new SelectList(db.Paarden, "PaardID", "Naam", orders.PaardID);
            return View(orders);
        }
```

This is essentially what i want.
[image: Form]

I've tried searching everywhere, but i couldn't find anything similar to what i want. Hopefully you guys can help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a work demo, you can refer to it.

1.Add `id` to ArtikelID, ArtikelBeschrijving,ArtikelPrijs, like below:

```
@Html.DropDownList("ArtikelID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" ,@id="list" })
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ArtikelBeschrijving, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" ,@id="id01"} })
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ArtikelPrijs, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id="id02" } })
```

2.Add below `<script>` to your Create view.

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/jscript">
  $(function() {
    $("#list").change(function() {
      var selectedid = $('option:selected').val();
     
        $.ajax({
          url: "/YourControllerName/GetDropDownList",
          data: {
            id: selectedid
          },
          type: "Post",
          dataType: "Json",
          success: function(result) {                 
              document.getElementById('id01').value = result.beschrijving;
              document.getElementById('id02').value =result.prijs;
          },
          error: function() {
           
          }
        });
      
    });
  });
</script>
```

3.In your Controller, add `GetDropDownList` action like below:

```
 [HttpPost]
  public IActionResult GetDropDownList(int id)
  {
   var result = db.Artikels.FirstOrDefault(m => m.ArtikelID == id);  
   return Json(result);
  }
```

Result:

[image]

**Update** get id

[image]

Comment: When is use firstordefault it gives result null

Comment: @ThomasAdelaars Can you get `id` in the `GetDropDownList(int id)`action ?

Comment: it's always 1 in the action

Comment: @ThomasAdelaars Which `ArtikelID`  do you choose?

Comment: doesn't matter what option i click, it always gives id = 1, while the values of the options are correct.

Comment: @ThomasAdelaars Try to  use `F12` ,then set breakpoint at ' var selectedid = $('option:selected').val();" in `Sources`, to see the value when you choose an option.

Comment: Hi @Thomas Adelaars, any update? If my answer help you resolve your issue, could you please accept as answer?
 If not, could you please follow up to let me know? 
Refer to:[How to access an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) Thanks.